# Tesseract confuses "-" and "7" in a single-line image

Tags: ocr, tesseract

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6Kzm.png) is recognized as
**08787365076858**, instead of 
**0878-3650-6858**

I have a list of 50 similar image files, and in each all "-" chars are matched as "7".

Default settings were used, even with installing tesseract to clear system.
Also tried to use -psm=7/8 (single line/word) and set whitelist characters.

What can be the reason of this issue and how can I overcome it? 
I know about training, but it's interesting, why accurate (in most cases) tesseract confuses so different chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rescaling to 300DPI would help get those dashes in the image.

Comment: Thanks. Stretching images to 390x50 solved the problem.

Comment: thanks guys, this was a good learning, pytesseract gives different results for different resolutions, playing with resizing images helped a lot (generally width 3 times height worked on my images).